# Finish lazy parentheses

Tags: code-golf, balanced-string

The parentheses on my keyboard are all worn out, and I want to avoid using them as much as possible. Your challenge is to balance a line containing parentheses by adding them in before and after each line.

This is similar to TI-Basic's automatic parentheses and string closure (i.e. `Output(1, 1, "Hello, World!`). It also saves precious bytes from a program!

Example input:

```
This line has no parentheses
alert(Math.max(1, 2
1+1)*2).toString()
function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })(
```

Example (possible) output:

```
This line has no parentheses
alert(Math.max(1, 2))
((1+1)*2).toString()
(function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })()
```

Specification:

- For each line of input,

  - Add as many open parentheses to the beginning and close parentheses to the end of the line as needed to balance the parentheses in the line

    - The definition of "balance" is:

      - Same amount of `(` and `)` in the line
      - For every substring starting from the beginning of the string, this substring must not have more closing parentheses than opening parentheses

        - For example, `(foo))(bar` is not balanced because `(foo))` has more closing parentheses than opening parentheses
  - You may add extra unnecessary parentheses if you want to, if it makes your code shorter
  - You do not need to worry about string literals or anything like that, assume that all parentheses need balancing
- Output each line with parentheses balanced

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes will win!

Comment: Are you just concerned with `()` parens, or do other brackets `{}`, `[]`, `<>`, etc need to be considered as well?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Nope, only `(` and `)`.

Comment: Do you have any test cases?

Comment: @Peter Yeah, they're right there in the post...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## GolfScript, 23 bytes

```
n/{"()"1/{.2$\-,*}%*n}/
```

The loophole I'm exploiting is the ruling that:

> You may add extra unnecessary parentheses if you want to, if it makes your code shorter

Basically, for each line, this code counts the number of characters on the line that are *not* opening parentheses, and prepends that many extra opening parentheses to the line, and then does the same for closing parentheses.  This is incredibly inefficient, but does ensure that all the parentheses on the output line are balanced.

For example, given the input:

```
This line has no parentheses
alert(Math.max(1, 2
1+1)*2).toString()
function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })(
```

this program will output:

```
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((This line has no parentheses))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
(((((((((((((((((alert(Math.max(1, 2)))))))))))))))))))
(((((((((((((((((1+1)*2).toString())))))))))))))))
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Ps. You can also [test this code online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IyBDYW5uZWQgaW5wdXQ6CjsiVGhpcyBsaW5lIGhhcyBubyBwYXJlbnRoZXNlcwphbGVydChNYXRoLm1heCgxLCAyCjErMSkqMikudG9TdHJpbmcoKQpmdW5jdGlvbigpIHsgYWxlcnQoJ0hlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEnKTsgfSkoIgoKIyBQcm9ncmFtOgpuL3siKCkiMS97LjIkXC0sKn0lKm59Lw%3D%3D).

Comment: This reminds me of when I used to program in Lisp... A few bits of code lost in a sea of parenthesis.

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, 32 = 31 + 1 or 73 = 72 + 1 (minimized parentheses)

### 32 = 31 + 1: with extra unnecessary parentheses

**Edits:**

- Fix, parentheses now counted with `y///`.
- Unnecessary variable `$a` removed.

```perl
$_="("x y/)//.s|$|")"x y/(//|er
```

It is used with the run-time switch `-p` (+1 byte).

**Test file `input.txt`:**

```
This line has no parentheses
alert(Math.max(1, 2
1+1)*2).toString()
function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })(
(foo))(bar
)))(((
((
))
```

**Command line:**

```bash
perl -p script.pl <input.txt
```

or

```bash
perl -pe '$_="("x y/)//.s|$|")"x y/(//|er' <input.txt
```

**Result:**

```
This line has no parentheses
alert(Math.max(1, 2))
(((1+1)*2).toString())
(((function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })()))
(((foo))(bar))
((()))((()))
(())
(())
```

**Ungolfed:**

The algorithm is simple, just add the counterpart for each found parentheses.

```perl
$_ =                     # $_ is provided as input by switch `-p` and
                         # it is printed afterwards as output.
                         # y/X// is used to count the character 'X' in $_
    '(' x y/)//          # add opening parentheses for each closing parentheses
    . s|$|')' x y/(//|er # go right before the end of line and insert
                         # closing parentheses for each opening parentheses
                         # in the original string
```

### 73 = 72 + 1: adding *minimum* number of parentheses

This script only adds the *minimum* number of parentheses to get a balanced output.

```perl
$a=y/()//cdr;1while$a=~s/\(\)//g;$_=$a=~y/)(/(/dr.$_;s|$|$a=~y/()/)/dr|e
```

It is used with the run-time switch `-p` (+1 byte).

```
perl -pe "$a=y/()//cdr;1while$a=~s/\(\)//g;$_=$a=~y/)(/(/dr.$_;s|$|$a=~y/()/)/dr|e" <input.txt
```

**Result:**

```
This line has no parentheses
alert(Math.max(1, 2))
((1+1)*2).toString()
(function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })()
((foo))(bar)
((()))((()))
(())
(())
```

**Ungolfed:**

```perl
$a = y/()//cdr;            # filter parentheses and store in $a
1 while $a =~ s/\(\)//g;   # remove matching parentheses
$_ = $a =~ y/)(/(/dr . $_; # add missing opening parentheses at start of string
s|$|$a=~y/()/)/dr|e        # insert missing closing parentheses at end of string
```

### 81 = 80 + 1: adding *minimum* number of parentheses

This is an older method to add the minimum number of parentheses for a balanced output.

```perl
my($l,$r);s/[()]/($&eq")"&&($r&&$r--||++$l))||$r++/ger;$_="("x$l.$_;s/$/")"x$r/e
```

It uses Perl 5.14 (because of the non-destructive substitution modifier) and the run-time switch `-p` (+1 byte).

```bash
perl -p script.pl <input.txt
```

**Result:**

```
This line has no parentheses
alert(Math.max(1, 2))
((1+1)*2).toString()
(function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })()
((foo))(bar)
((()))((()))
(())
(())
```

**Ungolfed:**

```perl
# The while loop is added by option "-p".
LINE:
while (<>) {

    # $_ contains the current line
    my ($l, $r); # initializes $l and $r (to undef/kind of indirect 0)
    # Modifiers for the following substitution of $_:
    # /g: process all parentheses
    # /e: evaluate code
    # /r: does not change the original input string $_ (Perl 5.14)
    s/[()]/
        # $& contains the matched parentheses
        # $r is a balance level counter; at the end $r contains
        #    the number of needed closing parentheses
        # $l is the number of needed opening parentheses;
        #    if $r would go negative, then an opening parentheses
        #    is missing and $l is increases and $r remains zero.
        (  
            $& eq ")" &&   # case ")"
            ($r && $r--    # close a parentheses group and update balance counter
                || ++$l)   # or update $l if an opening parentheses is needed
        )
        || $r++            # case "(": increase balance counter
    /ger;
    $_ = "(" x $l . $_;    # add opening parentheses at the begin of line
    s/$/")" x $r/e         # add closing parentheses before the line end

# the remainder is added by run-time switch "-p"
} continue {
    print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
}
```

Comment: Wow, that almost looks like golfscript ;-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek What perl are you using for the first version? It doesn't seem to work on 18.1 due to `'('x/\)/g` always equaling '('...

Comment: @Mouq: Thanks, fixed now using `y///` instead of `m//g` for counting the parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

## Python <strike>2.7</strike> 3: <strike>62</strike> <strike>60</strike> 58 bytes

```
while 1:s=input();c=s.count;print('('*c(')')+s+')'*c('('))
```

Not super golfed, but you know. I might be able to squeeze some more bytes out if I really tried.

For each line, outputs `(`*the number of `)` in the line, then the line, then `)`*the number of `(` in the line. If I understand the rules correctly, this will always provide valid output.

Exits by throwing an exception, as a result of the way I did input. (Input is always a hard part of these problems.) If this isn't acceptable, it'll cost me a few bytes to fix, though I'm not yet sure how many.

Example output:

```
This line has no parentheses
alert(Math.max(1, 2))
(((1+1)*2).toString())
(((function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })()))
```

Comment: This does not appear to take multiline input, i.e. prints are interspersed with lines of input. But nice algorithm idea, I didn't think of that ;)

Comment: `python2 balanced_parenthesis.py < input.txt 2>/dev/null` gets the output I wrote but if you want multiline input while doing it interactively it'll cost me a few bytes. Give me a second, I'll figure something out...

Comment: Ah, okay, never mind then. That will work!

Comment: save 2 chars: `while 1:s=raw_input();c=s.count;print'('*c(')')+s+')'*c('(')`

Comment: @qui Oh, wow. I came so close to figuring that out, but I didn't realize you could do `c=s.count`. I thought you had to do `c=s`, `s.c()`. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, why not do python 3 (save another 2 bytes)?: `while 1:s=input();c=s.count;print('('*c(')')+s+')'*c('('))`

Comment: @qui I should really make a habit of going over my solutions and making sure they wouldn't be any shorter in python 3. :P Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

## Pure Bash, 72 bytes

Uses the same algorithm as @undergroundmonorail's answer:

```
while read a;do
o=${a//[!(]}
c=${a//[!)]}
echo ${c//)/(}$a${o//(/)}
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./lazyparens.sh < input.txt
This line has no parentheses
alert(Math.max(1, 2))
(((1+1)*2).toString())
(((function() { alert('Hello, World!'); })()))
$
```